# Formatting Date from Date Object with only MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: java, android, parsing, date, parse-platform

Currently using Parse to obtain a date on an object by using:

```
Date date = object.getCreatedAt();
```

The returned String when displaying it in a TextView is this:

```
Mon Mar 17 22:39:27 CET 2014
```

However I really only want the MM/DD/YYYY to display like so: **3/17/2014**

I've tried this:

```
Date date = object.getCreatedAt();
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM DDD yyyy"); 
try {
    Date originaldate = originalFormat.parse(date.toString());
    finalDate = originaldate.toString();
} catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

but keep getting a ParseException for "Unparseable date", any idea what's going on? If I were to simply change this line back to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM DDD HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Then it prints out the full date again just fine with no parse exception, including all the date stuff I don't want.

Comment: What does `D` stand for? Also, does your string match the pattern?

Comment: You need to use a `SimpleDateFormat` to convert your date to a String, not the other way around.  Don't use `toString`.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));`

Comment: What D are you referring to? And the string that is normally being returned is Mon Mar 17 22:39:27 CET 2014 which is using the EEE MMM DDD HH:mm:ss z yyyy pattern, I do not want that, just the DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: how do you display it into TextView? just date.toString() ??

Comment: What does `D` represent in the `SimpleDateFormat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()

*java.util.Date.toString()* method always returns a String of format
`dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`
For example, *Thu Jan 10 02:00:00 EET 1992*.

Your Date format `"MMM DDD yyyy"` expects a date String like *Jan 10 1992* where 10 represents not 10th day of January but 10th day of year 1992.

Therefore to convert a date to String and convert it back to Date object using your format, you need to do

`Date originaldate = originalFormat.parse(originalFormat.parse(date.toString()));`

Or to convert *Date.toString()* to *Date* object,

`SimpleDateFormat toStringFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date originaldate = toStringFormat.parse(date.toString());`

Lastly, if you want a Date string with format like **3/17/2014**, the correct format is `M/d/yyyy`.
Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for help on how to write Date format.

Comment: Great thanks for the detailed information, I've accepted your answer simply because you hit on all points of the topic and went into great depth.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.  It doesn't even mention the `format` method of `SimpleDateFormatter`, which is the method that you need to solve this problem.  Writing `toStringFormat.parse(date.toString());` doesn't actually achieve anything - it doesn't format the date at all.  And `originalFormat.parse(originalFormat.parse(date.toString()));` doesn't even compile.  The one redeeming feature of this answer is the links to the Javadoc.

Comment: Really agree with you @DavidWallace. user3431085, Don't focus on a piece of code in an answer that corrected your issue, but look at the entire answer and understand how relevent it is. Don't forget, correct answers are not for us, but for new comers ...

Comment: @DavidWallace My bad on originalFormat.parse. Didn't review my answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `parse` method, use `format` instead :

```
Date date = object.getCreatedAt();
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
String datestring = formater.format(date); // value is : 3/17/2014
```

Comment: Great a lot closer...now I'm getting Mar/076/2014 , not sure where 076 as the date is coming from, odd. Also wish it would list it as 03 and not Mar, any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind got it thanks a lot man! Simply had to change it to MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: The complete list of available formats is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). I did `M` and not `MM`because in your question you wanted to have `3/17/2014` not `03/17/2014`. Happy that helped you ;)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer.  And `M/d/yyyy` is what the OP wants, so that they don't get leading zeroes.